# setting nan to entire axis if any nan exists in axis in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array with shape `(x,y,R)`. For each `(x,y)` pair, I have a 1D numpy array of R values. I want to set the entire array to `nan` if any of the R values are `nan` or `zero`. I tried something like

```
# 3d np array is called: data
mask1 = (data==0).any(axis=2)
mask2 = (data==np.nan).any(axis=2)
data[np.logical_or(mask1, mask2)] = np.nan
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I think the problem is the way I am trying to subset the `numpy array` with the **lower dimensional** boolean area, but not quite sure how to solve this.

Some example data:

```
y = np.random.random(size=(2,2,3))
y[0,0,2] = np.nan
y[0,1,0] = np.nan
y[0,0,1] = np.nan
y[1,1,2] = 0.
```

so that:

```
y[0,0,:]
array([0.092718,      nan,      nan])

y[0,1,:]
array([       nan, 0.00243745,        nan])

y[1,0,:]
array([0.5282173 , 0.7548559 , 0.08869139])

y[1,1,:]
array([0.19612415, 0.16969036, 0.0])
```

and the desired result:

```
y[0,0,:]
array([nan, nan, nan])

y[0,1,:]
array([nan, nan, nan])

y[1,0,:]
array([0.5282173 , 0.7548559 , 0.08869139])

y[1,1,:]
array([nan, nan, nan])
```

**update**

this seems to work, but perhaps there are more elegant appraoches:

```
mask1 = (y==0).any(axis=2)

y[np.logical_or(np.sum(np.isnan(y), axis=2) > 0, mask1)] = np.nan

    y
    array([[[       nan,        nan,        nan],
            [       nan,        nan,        nan]],

           [[0.5282173 , 0.7548559 , 0.08869139],
            [       nan,        nan,        nan]]])
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you provide some data.

Comment: Try using `np.isnan`; comparing with `nan` directly is not a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nan` has the peculiar property of comparing not equal to anything, *including* `nan` itself:

```
>>> y = np.random.random(size=(2,2,3))
>>> y[0,0,2] = np.nan
>>> y[0,1,0] = np.nan
>>> y[0,0,1] = np.nan
>>> y[0,1,2] = np.nan
>>> 
>>> y
array([[[0.03161193,        nan,        nan],
        [       nan, 0.55789282,        nan]],

       [[0.78047397, 0.06949872, 0.65225197],
        [0.84801579, 0.11298244, 0.07627531]]])
>>> 
>>> y == np.nan
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]]])
```

To check for `nan` you have to use `np.isnan`

```
>>> np.isnan(y)
array([[[False,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]]])
```

With this little modification your code will actually work:

```
>>> mask1 = (y==0).any(axis=2)
>>> mask2 = np.isnan(y).any(axis=2)
>>> y[np.logical_or(mask1, mask2)] = np.nan
>>> 
>>> y
array([[[       nan,        nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan]],

       [[0.78047397, 0.06949872, 0.65225197],
        [0.84801579, 0.11298244, 0.07627531]]])
```

Comment: haha , i just uploaded my question to have pretty much the same approach (based on your suggestion to use `np.isnan`)

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to [@PaulPanzer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49002512/2988730), I have attempted to get the same result with the minimum number of temp arrays. This answer is here for fun, and does not provide any benefits to outweigh the clarity and legibility of PaulPanzer's answer.

Instead of [`ndarray.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html), you can check for zeros directly with [`ndarray.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) and flip the 2D array in-place instead of the 3D, avoiding a temp array. You can use the property that any number added (or subtracted, multiplied, divided, etc) to `nan` results in `nan`. Instead of using `ndarray.any`, you can use [`ufunc.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) to make your 2D matrix, which will save you another 3D boolean array. You can't use the fact that [`np.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) is a [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) directly, because it is a unary function which does not support the `reduce` operation.

```
# Check for zeros
mask = y.all(axis=2)                   # Straight to 2D, no temp arrays
mask = np.logical_not(mask, out=mask)  # In place negation, no temp arrays

# Check for nans
nans = np.add.reduce(y, axis=2)        # 2D temp array, not 3D
mask |= np.isnan(nans)                 # Another temp array, also 2D
```

I chose to use [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) because it is not likely to run into problems that cause false `nan`s to appear (unlike say [`np.divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html)). Any overflows will become +/-`inf`, which will not trigger the `isnan` check.